# Function that involves averaging word length from a string?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, average

This is my first time ever touching JavaScript, and I am writing a function that will output the following:

- Individual words in the string,
- Total character count,
- Total word count,
- Whitespace count,
- and finally the average word length.

So far I have all aspects complete except I am struggling with the averaging process.

My code:

```
var superCounter = function(x) {
  var charCount = x.length;
  var wordCount = x.split(" ").length;
  var whiteSpace = wordCount - 1; 
  var wordArray = [x.split(" ")];
  var wordAvg = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < wordCount.length; i++){
    wordAvg += wordArray[i];
  }
  var avgLen = wordAvg / wordCount;
  console.log(("Words: " + wordArray[0]), "Character count: " + charCount, "Word count: " + wordCount, "Whitespace count: " + whiteSpace, "Word length average: " + avgLen);
};

superCounter("This function will analyze strings");
```

I like everything as it is except the averaging.

Output:

```
"Words: This,function,will,analyze,strings"
"Character count: 34"
"Word count: 5"
"Whitespace count: 4"
"Word length average: 0"
```

I know I somehow need the length of `i`, but every way I have attempted to apply `length` hasn't worked.

Ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: `i` is a number.  It doesn't have a length.  Do you mean the length of that element of the array? What did you try?

Comment: You add words (strings) to `wordAvg` (a number). Saying that using `length` "didn't work" won't help anybody diagnose, what specifically happened? What did you try?

Comment: Change this `var wordArray = [x.split(" ")];` to this `var wordArray = x.split(" ");` variable and then change this `wordAvg += wordArray[i];` to this `wordAvg += wordArray[i].length;`

Comment: It's the total number of characters divided by number of words, like this `var avgLen = wordArray.join('').length  / wordCount` -> http://jsfiddle.net/mo9Lqrkr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost had it, just a couple small changes and your code works great.

`wordArray` should be declared as follows:

```
var wordArray = x.split(" ");
```

Then you need to correct the summation of the word character lengths to `wordAvg`.

Change this:

```
wordAvg += wordArray[i];
```

To this:

```
wordAvg += wordArray[i].length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 wordAvg += wordArray[i];
```

should be

```
 wordAvg += wordArray[i].length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
var superCounter = function(x) {
    var charCount = x.length;
    var wordCount = x.split(" ").length;
    var whiteSpace = wordCount - 1; 
    var wordArray = x.split(" ");
    var wordAvg = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < wordCount; i++){
        wordAvg += wordArray[i].length;
    }
    var avgLen = wordAvg / wordCount;
    console.log(("Words: " + wordArray), "Character count: " + charCount, "Word count: " + wordCount, "Whitespace count: " + whiteSpace, "Word length average: " + avgLen);
};

superCounter("This function will analyze strings");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this :

```
 function jCounter(data) { 
     var strArr = data.split(' ');
     var strChar = data.length;
     var objStr = strArr.length;   
     var strSpaces = objStr - 1;

     var numArr = [];
     for (i=0; i<objStr; i++) {
        numArr.push(strArr[i].length); 
     }

     var sum = 0;
     for (i=0; i<numArr.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + numArr[i];
     } 

     var avg = sum/objStr;
     var strObj = {}; 

     strObj.words = objStr;
     strObj.chars = strChar;
     strObj.avgLength = avg ;
     strObj.spaces = strSpaces;

     console.log(strObj);
   } 

   jCounter("Coding is challenging");
```